# Wordpress + Chrome 59 - Change passwrod issue, caused by saved password

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, passwords

I have a WP installation (4.7.4) and I found an issue with Chrome 59

Scenario 1
I'm admin and I have my password saved on Chrome
I login to WP and I try to change password to another WP user "X".
When I submit my changes, Chrome fills password field with my saved password, so the user "X" gains my password. Chrome fills website field with string "admin" also.

Scenario 2
I'm a WP user and I have my password saved on Chrome.
If I try to change it with a new password, Chrome fills password field with my current password, so I cannot change it.

How I can fix WP code to prevent the scenarios, without asking users to do not save their passwords?

Thanks

Diego

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606